# Checkbox not working when repeating using Angular ng-repeat directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

Hi I am creating checkboxes using Angular ng-repeat directive.But when clicking on the checkboxes, they are not getting checked/unchecked. I am also using bootstrap css. here is the code snippet which I have used

```
<div id="regionCheckBox" class="span12">
      <span ng-repeat="region in histCtrl.regions">
            <label for="{{'regionCheckbox'+$index}}" >
                 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="RegionCheckBox" id="{{'regionCheckbox'+$index}}" value="{{region}}" />
                  {{region}}
            </label>
      </span>
</div>
```

Here is the generated code when inspected through  fire-bug

```
<span class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="region in histCtrl.regions">
    <label class="ng-binding" for="regionCheckbox0">
      <div id="uniform-regionCheckbox0" class="checker">
         <span>
           <input id="regionCheckbox0" class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="ASIA" name="RegionCheckBox" style="opacity: 0;">
         </span>
      </div>
      ASIA
    </label>
</span>
```

I have tried with static code and it's working and it's code snippet is given below

```
<div class="span12">
     <label for="checkbox0">
           <input class="checkbox" id="checkbox0" type="checkbox" name="group"/> test0
     </label>
     <label for="checkbox1">
            <input class="checkbox" id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="group"/> test0
     </label>
     <label for="checkbox2">
             <input class="checkbox" id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="group"/> test0
     </label>
 </div>
```

I can't understand why it's not working and also clicking on the label is also not triggering click on checkbox.

Edit: This is not the issue with Angular. We were using a jquery plugin which would style all form elements and it is modifying the DOM, and thus this inconsistent behavior is observed. Be very careful, how you manipulate DOM when using angular.

Answer (score 2):

Just no need for for in the label the following code works fine for me

```
<div id="regionCheckBox" class="span12">
  <span ng-repeat="region in histCtrl">
        <label >{{'regionCheckbox'+$index}}
             <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="RegionCheckBox" id="{{'regionCheckbox'+$index}}" value="{{region}}" ng-click="test($index)" />
              {{region}}
        </label>
  </span>
```

in my controller

```
$scope.histCtrl = ['a','b','c']; 
$scope.test =function(id){alert(id)};
```

and i also get the alert with index

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as shown and refer [this demo of handling checkboxes - angularJS](http://embed.plnkr.co/g0NMG4rmF4uwzoG2uZhf/preview)

[this also will help](http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/handling-checkboxes-and-radio-buttons-in-angular-forms)

`id="regionCheckbox{{$index}}"` instead of `id="{{'regionCheckbox'+$index}}"` and

`<label for="{{'regionCheckbox'+$index}}" > to <label for="regionCheckbox{{$index}}" >`

```
<div id="regionCheckBox" class="span12">
      <span ng-repeat="region in histCtrl.regions">
            <label for="regionCheckbox{{$index}}" >
                 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="RegionCheckBox" id="regionCheckbox{{$index}}" value="{{region}}" />
                  {{region}}
            </label>
      </span>
</div>
```

Comment: same result.I have checked with DOM element inspector, the checked property is getting changed from true to false and vice versa, but it is not reflected in UI and clicking on label is not triggering the checkbox checked property.

Comment: @saiki4116 modified the answer, please refer the links that i provided, will help you

Comment: Bootstrap is converting checkbox to a div with class='checker' containing <span> child with class=""(not checked state) and class="checked"(checked state), but for the checkboxes generated with ng-repeat the span does not have any class and the dom property changes are not getting reflected on the UI, as the class is not getting changed to "" to "checked" and vice-versa